# window.location.replace JS

Tags: javascript

What does the following code return?

```
window.location.replace("/ak012/(S(sar23pq1ki5wo22qqmmidvie))/HTML/Page.ashx?ID=4")
```

Comment: I don't really understand...Why didn't you try yourself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"/ak012/(S(sar23pq1ki5wo22qqmmidvie))/HTML/Page.ashx?ID=4"` - is a URL string
`window.location.replace(URL_STRING)` - redirects to that URL

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, it changes the browser's location (redirects) to the url specified, **without** adding it to the browser history. Introduced in Javascript 1.1. [Documentation here](http://docs.sun.com/source/816-6408-10/location.htm#1194240).

Answer (score 1):

The replace() loads the specified URL over the current history entry. So when you use the replace method, the user cannot navigate to the previous URL by using Navigator's Back button.

The argument inside the replace is your url :

```
/ak012/(S(sar23pq1ki5wo22qqmmidvie))/HTML/Page.ashx?ID=4
```

Answer (score 1):

As Matt says, it returns undefined. 
It is a method for navigating to another document.

I just want to add to the answers here a warning that IE does not register a referrer when navigating using the document.location properties and methods.

My solution to this was to create a hidden A element in the document and programatically click that link.

Example HMTL:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" id="hidden-link" style="display: none"><!-- Blank --></a>
```

Example JavaScript:

```
var hiddenAElement = document.getElementById('hidden-link');

if ( document.all ) // Very simple IE detection.
{
    hiddenAElement.click();   
}
else
{
   document.location.href = hiddenAElement.href;
}
```